# how to install hammock API library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, hammock

I am not able to install hammock API library for .NET in visual studio, i have installed NuGet but dont know how to install hammock from the location below, so that i can use it in my project.

```
https://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock
```

I am using visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution explorer:

References -> Manage Nuget Packages

On the left side click Online.

On the top right side, inside the search field type hammock.

Click install.